# Correct Semantic Versioning Change for Swift Version Update

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, semantic-versioning, podspec

What is the correct semantic versioning change to make when updating a podspec for a new Swift version?

For example, I am currently updating my project to Swift 5.1 (and therefore Xcode 11). The changes to the source code are only Swift 5.1 tweaks like [implicit returns from single-expression functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0255-omit-return.md). The underlying API, functionality and iOS deployment target is not changing at all.

Typically, I would increment the PATCH version by 1, but I've honestly never been sure because of how https://semver.org/ describes what to increment:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

I'm not making API changes, adding new functionality or fixing any bugs, but I still need to change the version in my podspec.

I think this is an objective question, but the community can feel free to vote it down if not ;P

Comment: I would consider it a "Patch"

Comment: I'd increment MINOR and change PATCH to 0. (If it is 100% backwards-compatible)

Comment: On a slightly different note, I had a similar question on a pre-release version 0.x of my pod. In my case I was making breaking changes to the public api. But should I start using the major version 1.x for a pre release?

Comment: @grooveplex Mind explaining why you’d increment on MINOR? Just trying to clear up some of the ambiguity around this question. The way I see it is that removing some `return`s isn’t actually adding functionality.

Comment: It's a broad definition of "functionality", for sure. But it's not a breaking change and not a bug fix… :-)